# How do you make a BTreeMap with byte array keys?

Tags: rust

Just starting to (try to) learn Rust. How do I use "bytestrings" as keys in a std::collections::BTreeMap?

It seems like I can't use [u8] because the type requires a fixed size.

Using vectors, e.g.

```
BTreeMap<Vec<u8>, MyType>
```

...seems wasteful.

I could try concatting all the bytestrings into one Vec and use slices of that as the BTree keys, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What ultimately owns your bytestrings?

Comment: Could you explain more why "using vectors seems wasteful"?

Comment: I was just thinking of over-allocation and whatever bookkeeping overhead a vector has. But I suppose I could shrink the vectors to fit before putting them in map.

Comment: `Vec` by itself is [pretty bare-bones](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f11f3e7baeba3f5acf08cc6fbfee559c00e9f96e/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L136-L140), just a pointer, a length, and a capacity. Shrinking it could be useful, as could putting it all in one place and just using slices (which are just a pointer and a length). What's the ballpark number of keys and how long are they on average? Is it worth worrying about this level of minutia (a.k.a. have you benchmarked)? ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let key1 = b"1234";
    let key2 = b"5678";

    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();

    map.insert(key1, true);
    map.insert(key2, false);

    println!("{}", map);
}
```

As you saw, `[u8]` is a type that doesn't have any size, which means you can't actually *store* one of them somewhere. Instead, you will want to store a "slice of u8s", written `&[u8]`, as the key. In this example, I just created some throw-away slices, but yours will likely come from some owning object.

Comment: I was hoping I could somehow have the BTreeMap own the keys, since that's the only place they need to be. If that's not possible, I'll have the object holding the BTreeMap also hold a big Vec<u8> of all the bytes concatenated and use slices of it as the keys.

Comment: You cannot express sibling lifetimes, so you won't be able to have one object that both owns the bytestrings and has references to those bytestrings. It is not possible to ensure that the references will be valid for the appropriate length.